# Phase 10 - After laying down a phase, do you still draw a card on your turn?

Tags: phase-10

Me and my friends are playing Phase 10 and we all grew up playing it two different ways and we don’t know what the correct way is.
After you put down your phase and are trying to get rid of your cards:

- Do you just discard without drawing

or

- Do you have to draw a card and try to put it onto yours and other people’s phases that is on the table?

Answer (score 3):

You still must draw like normal; the only way to reduce your hand size is to hit on existing phases.

From [the rules](http://www.tactic.net/site/rules/FIN/03140.pdf) about taking your turn:

> On your turn, draw one card, either the top card from the draw pile or the top
> card from the discard pile, and add it to your hand. End your turn by discarding any
> one of your cards onto the top of the discard pile.

There is no rule listed under going out or making a phase that contradicts or changes this, so it still applies.